# What kind of beer for beer bread?

Tags: baking, bread, beer

Beer bread is bread wherein beer is used for liquid and leavening. I tend to use a basic pilsner, but I'm a beer snob, and I've taken to wondering what would happen if I substituted something a little more exotic.

Has anyone tried this? I don't want to do trial-and-error with expensive beer if I don't have to.

Comment: I love using Guiness or some other stout (chocolate, coffee, oatmeal...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used dark beer with good results. It just depends on what flavor you desire.  I often use Lion stout, for example, which imparts a strong, intense flavor and color, which I quite like, but it would not be appropriate for all applications.  Also Sierra Nevada porter has happily found its way into my bread. Keep in mind that these beers may be *too* strongly flavored for your taste, in which case you can add some lighter beer to balance it out (lager or pilsner).

Personally I don't like to add pale ales to bread as I don't enjoy the way the hop flavor comes through, but this comes down to personal preference.

In general, the flavor of the beer will come through in the bread, but you won't notice all of the subtleties of flavor that you do when drinking, so I wouldn't put too expensive a beer in bread--the bread will turn out fine, but you're not going to appreciate the beer to its fullest.

Comment: I keep thinking about sweet bread with brown beer. I tend to drink really hoppy beer though, so hmmmm...

Comment: Yes, I love to drink hoppy beer, too, so I say drink the hoppy beer and cook the malty beer! A nut brown ale would be something to try for sure--I haven't yet.

Comment: Agree, darker, maltier, sweeter beers are the way to go. Think about flavors that will go well with butter!

Answer (score 0):

I used Anchor Steam and it was the best so far. Definately stay away frim Pale Ale or Ale.